# location.getlocation() gives casting error on android flutter

Tags: android, flutter, location

First importing and initializing the location package:

```
import 'package:location/location.dart' as locationPackage;

locationPackage.Location location = new locationPackage.Location();
```

On android running the code:

```
try {
  await location.getLocation().then((pos) {
    setState(() {
      print(pos.runtimeType);
      _center = LatLng(pos.latitude, pos.longitude);;
      _lastMapPosition = _center;
    });
  });
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
  if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
   print("Permission Denied");
  }
}
}
```

Gives the error:

```
I/flutter ( 4326): NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method 'cast'.
I/flutter ( 4326): Receiver: 1
I/flutter ( 4326): Tried calling: cast<String, double>()
E/flutter ( 4326): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'NoSuchMethodError' has no instance getter 'code'.

E/flutter ( 4326): Receiver: Instance of 'NoSuchMethodError'
E/flutter ( 4326): Tried calling: code
E/flutter ( 4326): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
E/flutter ( 4326): #1      _MapsSearchPageState._getLocation (package:Bartr/maps.dart:486:13)
E/flutter ( 4326): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4326): #2      _MapsSearchPageState.initState (package:Bartr/maps.dart:500:5)
E/flutter ( 4326): #3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:58)
E/flutter ( 4326): #4      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3717:5)
E/flutter ( 4326): #5      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2961:14)
E/flutter ( 4326): #6      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2764:12)
E/flutter ( 4326): #7      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
E/flutter ( 4326): #8      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2961:14)
E/flutter ( 4326): #9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2764:12)
E/flutter ( 4326): #10     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
E/flutter ( 4326): #11     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
E/flutter ( 4326): #12     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3722:5)
E/flutter ( 4326): #13     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3717:5)
E/flutter ( 4326): #14     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2961:14)
E/flutter ( 4326): #15     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2764:12)
E/flutter ( 4326): #16     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
E/flutter ( 4326): #17     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2961:14)
E/flutter ( 4326): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2764:12)
E/flutter ( 4326): #19     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
E/flutter ( 4326): #20     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2961:14)
E/flutter ( 4326): #21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2764:12)
E/flutter ( 4326): #22     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
E/flutter ( 4326): #23     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2961:14)
E/flutter ( 4326): #24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2764:12)
E/flutter ( 4326): #25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
E/flutter ( 4326): #26     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2961:14)
E/flutter ( 4326): #27     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2764:12)
E/flutter ( 4326): #28     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
E/flutter ( 4326): #29     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
E/flutter ( 4326): #30     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3722:5)
E/flutter ( 4326): #31     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
E/flutter ( 4326): #32     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3717:5)
E/flutter ( 4326): #33     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2961:14)
E/flutter ( 4326): #34     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2764:12)
E/flutter ( 4326): #35     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
E/flutter ( 4326): #36     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
E/flutter ( 4326): #37     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3722:5)
E/flutter ( 4326): #38     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3717:5)
E/flutter ( 4326): #39     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2961:14)
E/flutter ( 4326): #40     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2764:12)
E/flutter ( 4326): #41     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
E/flutter ( 4326): #42     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
E/flutter ( 4326): #43     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3722:5)
E/flutter ( 4326): #44     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
E/flutter ( 4326): #45     Componen
```

This only happens on android. Firebase and all other packages appear to be working. I have followed the most modern installation rules for `package:location/location.dart`. I am using version  2.3.5 and flutter doctor shows all checkmarks for android development.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Please share the code which you use `cast` method

Comment: @PhanVanLinh I do not use the 'cast' method. I know that it is this code that causes the error though as if I replace this block, with instead initializing _center with a hardcoded position no error is given.

Comment: Can you share the code . of  `_getLocation`

Comment: Just ignore above comment. I thought it would be some of your code causing it. Once I took a look into plugin code, seems it's seems the plugin causing the cast error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue might be calling `location.getLocation` without checking for permissions. Looking at the plugin [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location#-readme-tab-), if you invoke the [`getLocation`](https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/blob/master/lib/location.dart#L60) method without checking for permissions, the native [call here](https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/lyokone/location/LocationPlugin.java#L153) invoked automatically checks for permission, requests if not available. The result returned for permission request is an integer and hence the cast error.

An issue should be raised regarding this at the plugin [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location#-readme-tab-) to either return proper results or throw appropriate errors.

You can try check for permission and then call `location.getLocation()`

Example:

```
void _getLocation() async {
    Location location = Location();
    if (await location.hasPermission()) {
        final LocationData pos = await location.getLocation();
        setState(() {
            print(pos.runtimeType);
            _lastMapPosition = pos;
        });
    } else {
        await location.requestPermission();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, it works! I did some additional testing and learned that the reason for the error is that the function is called from the initstate method. So when we use this code because of the additional asynchronicity of `await location.hasPermission()` it works.

Comment: Great! Good luck!

Comment: location.hasPermission is not a boolean anymore it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using geolocator 5.3.1 by baseflow.com
https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator#-readme-tab-

and read the tutorial here:
https://alligator.io/flutter/geolocator-plugin/

Tested working on my Android Studio emulator